# How to pass data from alert dialog after selecting a radio button to main screen

Tags: flutter

I have implemented 4 radio button tiles in alert dialog and want to pass data on OK Button after selecting any of the radio button and show it to the main screen or it is possible way to store the data by shared preference and then send

```
class _MethodState extends State<Method> {
  int _crtIndex = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Methods"),
      content: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          RadioListTile(value: 1, groupValue: _crtIndex,
              title: Text("A"),
              activeColor: Colors.teal,
              onChanged: (val){
                setState(() {
                  _crtIndex = val;


                });
              }),
          RadioListTile(value: 2, groupValue: _crtIndex,
              title: Text("B"),
              activeColor: Colors.teal,
              onChanged: (val){
                setState(() {
                  _crtIndex = val;
                });
              }),
          RadioListTile(value: 3, groupValue: _crtIndex,
              title: Text("C"),
              activeColor: Colors.teal,
              onChanged: (val){
                setState(() {
                  _crtIndex = val;
                });
              }),
          RadioListTile(value: 4, groupValue: _crtIndex,
              title: Text("D"),
              activeColor: Colors.teal,
              onChanged: (val){
                setState(() {
                  _crtIndex = val;
                });
              }),
actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () {
// pass data
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

```
onPressed: () async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setInt('radio.value', _crtIndex);
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

And to get it in anywhere in your app

```
getSelectedValue() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int radioValue = prefs.getInt('radio.value');
//  check if radioValue is null - no button is pressed yet, otherwise you will have selected radio value here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function as a parameter while opening `AlertDialog` from main screen, and call this function on pressing `OK` in `AlertDialog`.

Here is an example for this.

```
class Method extends StatefulWidget {
    Function functionFromMain;
    Method({Key key, @required this.functionFromMain}) : super(key: key);
}
```

Now as per your code add below line on pressing `OK`.

```
onPressed: () {
    widget.functionFromMain(_crtIndex);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
```

Now while opening this Method widget in your Main class,

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Method(functionFromMain: yourFunction,)));
```

Comment: is there a way to store the data by shared preference while clicking on OK Button

Comment: How to store selected radio button by shared preference while Clicking OK button

Comment: added another answer.